# Opening Different Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

OK, can't find a solution to this.

A client sent me his **Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web** project. I have **Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2010** installed.
I get an error when I try to open his project saying "this project is not compatible with the current version of visual studio".

We'll be passing the project back & forth quite a bit, so I need a solution that meets that need please.

So, I figure I may be able to modify the project with a text editor to let me open it. If so, do I have to re-edit it back when I send it back to him?

Can I install VS Express 2012 for Web on a machine that already has VS Ultimate 2010 on it without any conflicts?  Can I open it if I install VS 2012 Ultimate (keeping 2010 as well)?

I have another client that uses 2010, so whatever I do, I need to be able to still support him.

If I can't have 2 versions installed at the same time, and can't easily edit a file to make it compatible, then I guess my last option is a virtual machine.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio has backwards compatibility since the version 2010 SP1.

So in this case you just need update your Visual Studio 2010 to SP1 and it will understand the new way files are versioned.

Comment: What should resolve this problem? Update to SP1? I'm already running SP1.

Comment: Yes. With the SP1 they introduced the possibility to open new projects in older versions. Like create a VS2013 project and open with VS2010 SP1, no conversion needed. Perhaps a deficiency in using Express version. The example I just gave works for me.

Comment: OK, but I am already running SP1. It is already updated. But I still can't open the project.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience:

1. You do can edit it with a text file and send it back, but it's not compiled yet so it's your partners job.
2. Maybe, just maybe, you can edit the .sln and .(whatever the project file extension is) file to meet your VS10 env (I think it's going to be a bumpy road though)
3. Yes, I'm  pretty sure you can have VS 10 and VS 12 installed on same machine, note that you have to have .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5